# Predicate retruns false when callled from other predicate

Tags: prolog

I have this program in Prolog

```
su([], Counter, Counter).
su([G|O], N, Count) :- Counter is Count + G, su(O,N,Counter).

custom_sum(L,X) :- su(L,X,0).

write_file :-
   write('Type list: '),
   read(L1),
   tell('file.txt'),
      write(L1), write(.), nl,
   told.

read_file :-
   write('Reading from file...'), nl,
   see('file.txt'),
      read(L),
   seen,
   write('sum of list elements: '),
   custom_sum(L,Sum),
   write(Sum), assertz(my_sum(Sum)).
```

When I try to use custom_sum, everything is fine. Same with write_file. But read_file returns false right after "write('sum of list elements: ')". As if custom_sum was a problem here.

Comment: Hmmm, [Edinburgh-style I/O](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=edinburghIO). Interesting. Quick hacks live on forever (or at least 40+ years). What happens when you write out `L`  right after `seen`?

Comment: Which Prolog system are you using? SWI-Prolog?

Comment: @David Tonhofer it just writes the L on output, nothing out of ordinary

Comment: @Guy Coder Newest swi-prolog from Manjaro pacman manager

Comment: Can you show the version of SWI-Prolog. e.g. mine is `Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.24)`

Comment: If this is an exercise unless it is to learn to write to a file there should be no reason to write to a file to save values for a simple calculation.

Comment: As noted by David the use of the predicates like `tell` and `seen` is so old I don't even use them and I have been using Prolog since the 1980's when they were the norm, but no longer. It would help if you posted the details of the exercise because odds are you will move off these predicates and we will have wasted quite a bit of time on them. I don't plan to answer this as it is posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity I ran your code without changing anything. Your code works as I would expect on my system with SWI-Prolog on Windows 10.

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.24)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit https://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- consult("C:/Users/Groot/Documents/Projects/Prolog/SO_question_180.pl").
true.

?- custom_sum([1,2,3],R).
R = 6.

?- working_directory(Working_directory,'C:/Users/Groot/Documents/Projects/Prolog/SO_question_180/').
Working_directory = 'c:/users/groot/documents/prolog/'.

?- working_directory(D,D).
D = 'c:/users/groot/documents/projects/prolog/so_question_180/'.

?- write_file.
Type list: [1,2,3].

true.

?- read_file.
Reading from file...
sum of list elements: 6
true.

?-
```

My only guess is that you are entering the list incorrectly at the prompt.

It should be `[1,2,3].`  You need the `[ ]` and the ending period `.` .

---

Contents of created `file.txt`

```
[1,2,3].
```